# Создание файлов

Tags: python, файлы

Есть скрипт по созданию файлов в диске D . Этот скрипт запускается через бат-файл.
При запуске этого бат-файла в  диске D - файлы не создаются ,но при запуске скрипта вне папки диска D - файлы успешно создаются .Скрипт по созданию файлов:

```
import sys 
print("======FileErrorVirus======") 
#stop = input("Write stop to stop") 
names = ["File1","File2","File3","File4","File5"] 
howmuch = "6" 
namesmore = "File" 
crash = True 
write = "" 
while crash == True: 
    result = howmuch + namesmore 
    names.append(result) 
    howmuch += "1" 
    while len(write) < 30: 
        write +="_First Virus_" 
    if len(names) > 3: 
        crash = False 

for file in names: 
    some = open("D:  " + file + ".txt" ,"w",encoding = "utf- 8") 

    some.write(write)
```

Главный вопрос - почему так происходит , и как решить это дело .

Comment: У вас имена файлов получаются вида D:File.txt, а должно быть D:\File1.txt. 
Вместо `"D:  " + file + ".txt"` рекомендую использовать `os.path.join()`.

Comment: @Michael Belyakov Вот так?:some = open(os.path.join("D: " + file + ".txt"),"w",encoding = "utf- 8")P.S Если так - то не работает

Comment: Скорее вот так `some = open(os.path.join("D:\\", file + ".txt"),"w",encoding = "utf- 8")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас имена файлов получаются вида D:File1.txt. При использовании таких имён файлы открываются в текущем каталоге. Думаю, что вам нужно указать какой-то конкретный каталог, например, D:\File1.txt. Кроме того, для формирования пути рекомендуется использовать [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).
Таким образом код открытия файла будет таким

```
some = open(os.path.join("D:\\", file + ".txt"), "w", encoding = "utf-8")
```

Затем, для работы с файлами рекомендуется использовать менеджеры контекста `With ... as`.

```
with open(os.path.join("D:\\", file + ".txt"), "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    pass
```

В таком случае вам не надо заботиться о корректном закрытии файла, он будет закрыт автоматически при выходе из блока.